# What does "User was removed" means in a profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

What does *"User was removed"* mean in a user profile? I just noticed in [my reputation tab](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/25245/woj?tab=reputation) that I was "awarded" -5 points with this explanation.

Which user (I guess it's me) was removed from where, and for what reason? (there are no further links to a question or something)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

5 points is the number of reputation points you receive when someone votes one of your questions up.

It's most likely that someone who had voted up one of your questions in the recent past has been banned or deleted, so their impact on the site has been automatically reversed.

See also: [“User was removed” means I lose my hard-earned points?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187605/133427)